# Ajax append to a variable with condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, append

This is my code:

```
 $.ajax('http://mydb.php', {
     dataType: "json",
     jsonp: "jsoncallback",
     method: 'get',
     contentType: 'application/json',
     success: function (data, status) {
         var _ul = $('<ul />').attr('data-role', 'listview');

         $.each(data, function (i, item) {
             $('<li />').append($('<a href="#p'+item.id+'" >'+item.nome+'</a>'))
             .appendTo(_ul);
             var makePage = $('<div id="header">');
             //append </div> to makepage var
             makePage.appendTo($.mobile.pageContainer);
         });

         $('#output').empty().append(_ul).enhanceWithin();//.listview();
     },
     error: function (xhr, d, s) {
         $('#output').empty().html(s);
     }
 });
```

I want to append content to `var makePage`. I need something like this:

```
if ( item.something != " " )
```

And append to `makePage` the following:

```
<div>something to print since item.something is not empty</div>
```

And of course at the end I have to close all "divs" opened at the begin of `makePage` variable.

How do I do it? You could say I have done the same thing with `<ul>` and `<li>` before, but I'm not able to do the same with the `makePage` var.

Comment: Would be useful if you could provide an example of the data being returned from the ajax request and the HTML on your page.

Comment: @almcd it's returned a jquery mobile page with address book. Basically, it returns all fields , even if they are empty. But if I could append datas one per time, i could say "if this field is not empty, print it". I hope you have understood..